# Error when using a subquery in SQL to find community with maximum number of crimes

Tags: python, sql

I am working on a project using a Python notebook in which I am required to find the community name with the maximum number of crimes. For this data from two tables, [Chicago Crime Data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-Present/ijzp-q8t2/data) and [Chicago Census Data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Health-Human-Services/Census-Data-Selected-socioeconomic-indicators-in-C/kn9c-c2s2/data), needs to be accessed. I can do this without using a subquery as follows.

```
%sql SELECT CENSUS.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, CRIME.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, COUNT(CRIME.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER) \
as "Number of crimes in this community" \
FROM CHICAGOCRIMEDATA CRIME, CHICAGOCENSUSDATA CENSUS WHERE CRIME.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER IS NOT NULL \
GROUP BY CRIME.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, CENSUS.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME ORDER BY COUNT(CRIME.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER)\
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I tried to do this using a subquery but am not sure how.

```
%sql SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, COUNT(*) \
FROM CHICAGOCRIMEDATA WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER IS NOT NULL \
GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(*) = 43;
```

I get an error when I try to find the maximum number of crimes using a subquery instead of the known value of 43.

```
%sql SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, COUNT(*) \
FROM CHICAGOCRIMEDATA WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER IS NOT NULL \
GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(*) = (select max(count(*)) from CHICAGOCRIMEDATA);
```

Does anyone know how to use a subquery to find the community area name with the most crimes? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any actual Python code in this question - can you [edit] to remove the Python tag and add a tag for the database that you are using?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and limit the results to one row.  The SQL Standard syntax is:

```
SELECT COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, COUNT(*)
FROM CHICAGOCRIMEDATA
WHERE COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Many databases also support just `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
%sql SELECT CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, CD.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, COUNT(CR.ID) AS CRIME_NO \
FROM CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA AS CR, CENSUS_DATA AS CD \
WHERE CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = CD.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER \
GROUP BY CR.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER,  CD.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME \
ORDER BY CRIME_NO DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWHdP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.